# Reading all properties of web using Javascript object model

Tags: csom, jsom, property-bag

We can read the web properties using javascript object model as

```
var webProperties = web.get_allProperties()
```

and then to fetch a property value we can index it using

```
webProperties.get_fieldValues()["PropertyName"]
```

However if I have to read **all** the properties of the web, I cannot simply iterate it using indexes.

webProperties.get_fieldValues()[1] or     webProperties.get_fieldValues().get_item(1)

does not work.

We need to know the **key** to be able to retrieve the value of a property. Apparantely, to fetch all the web properties, I have to log it in the console or debug and WATCH the value. Any solutions on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
var properties = webProperties.get_fieldValues();

// loop over all properties
for (property in properties) 
{
   var propertyName = property;
   var propertyValue = properties[property];

   console.log(propertyName + " - " + propertyValue);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work ! Did you get any result from the above code ? I have loaded the "web" object in my client query and trying to get the code working in the success handler. Of course with a "var property" in the FOR loop.

Comment: ah well this worked..thanks. I had not loaded the properties explicitly. Cheers !